# Vue.js 2 removes element

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this simple `index.html` with JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>fghfghfgh</title>
        </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chat">
            <form v-on:submit="send" method="post" action="">
                <input type="" v-model="message" name="">
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul id="messages">
                <li v-repeat="message: messages">{{message}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript"src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<script>
       new Vue({
           el: '#chat',
           data: {
               message: '',
               messages: []
           },
           methods: {
               send: function (event) {
                   event.preventDefault();
               }
           }
        })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I load the page, it removes entire `form` element, including `input` and `button`. If I remove `li` element from `index.html`, it not removes the form.
Why is that and how to fix it ?

Comment: try `v-for="message in messages"` instead of your `v-repeat`. That changed from Vue v1 to Vue v2

Comment: Thanks, it works.